# Is Coherent sheaf acyclic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

I am no expert in sheaf theory so the following question may be trivial. Let $X$ a complex manifold, and let $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $X$. Is $\mathcal{F}$ acyclic? If not: can you give a counterexample?

I don't know if somebody else asked the same question: in that case sorry for repetition.

Comment: Did you look up what it means for a sheaf to be acyclic? From Wikipedia: "An acyclic sheaf $F$ over $X$ is one such that all higher sheaf cohomology groups vanish." That should give you a very strong hint what the answer must be.

Comment: It depends on what you call a manifold. A quasi-coherent sheaf is acyclic on an affine scheme for instance.

Comment: @Nefertiti Ok, in general this is not true! I'm reading the Griffiths-Harris: principle of algebraic geometry, and I confused the notion of acyclic sheaf and acyclic covering for the sheaf.

Comment: @GianlucaFaraco: right! Otherwise "sheaf cohomology" would not be a very useful tool! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest counterexample is the sheaf of holomorphic differential $1$-forms $\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^1}=\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)$ on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb P^1=\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$.
It is  coherent but not acyclic since  $$H^1(\mathbb P^1,\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^1})= \mathbb C$$